Handle package versioning between remote application in NX monorepo workspace
I'm working in NX monorepo workspace with different remote applications, My shell application is using angular 17 dependency from root package.json. I have a requirement to create new remote application which uses angular 14, to solve this Issue I have created a package.json with angular 14 dependencies and ran npm i to create node modules.
how can I verify that my remote app is using angular 14 dependency, And when I am trying to share my angular dependencies from  webpack config by using share as follow
module.exports = new withModuleFederationPlugin({
    shared: share({
        "@angular/core": {singleton:true, requiredVersion:'^14.2.0', strictVersion:false},
        "@angular/common": {singleton:true, requiredVersion:'^14.2.0', strictVersion:false},
        "@angular/common/http": {singleton:true, requiredVersion:'^14.2.0', strictVersion:false},
        "@angular/router": {singleton:true, requiredVersion:'^14.2.0', strictVersion:false},
        "@angular/compiler": {singleton:true, requiredVersion:'^14.2.0', strictVersion:false},
    }),
    
})

when I try to share the angular dependencies I'm getting following error
enter image description here
